# Magento 2.4.5-p1 main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/

Tags: magento2, page-builder

I need some assistance, please.
My pagebuilder is not showing any icons.
In debug.log I get the following errors.

```
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.434545+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/preview.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.434722+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/preview.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.512476+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-menu/edit.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.512638+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-menu/edit.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.520366+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/sortable-children.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.520799+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/sortable-children.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.534099+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/live-edit.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.534300+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/binding/live-edit.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.536423+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/check-stage-full-screen.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.541046+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-menu.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.541576+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-menu.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.541822+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/check-stage-full-screen.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.554475+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/sortable.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.554640+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/sortable.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.561822+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-menu/title-option.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.561982+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-menu/title-option.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.561888+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-menu/option.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.562543+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-menu/option.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.569992+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/move-content-type.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:05.570311+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/drag-drop/move-content-type.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:06.434837+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/read/configurable.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:06.435205+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/read/configurable.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:06.440534+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/property-reader-pool.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:06.440703+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/property-reader-pool.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:06.441159+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/property-reader-pool-factory.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:06.441502+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/property-reader-pool-factory.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:07.476196+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/style-property-reader.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:07.482809+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/style-property-reader.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:07.486473+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/margins.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:07.486810+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/margins.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:07.512405+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/display.js.map' [] []
[2023-03-24T09:40:07.514908+00:00] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/paddings.js.map' [] []
```

[Pagebuilder edit icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7CvO.png)[image: Pagebuilder Sidebar]

[image: Pagebuilder Edit Icons]

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify the existence of the file: Make sure that the file 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/[filename].js' actually exists in your Magento installation. Check the path and ensure that the file is present.
2. Clear Magento caches: Run the following command from your Magento root directory to clear the cache:

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   ```
3. Additionally, you can try removing the contents of the var/cache directory manually.

- Deploy static content: If you have recently installed or updated the Page Builder module, you may need to deploy the static content. Run the following command:

  ```
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
  ```

4. Check file permissions: Ensure that the file and its parent directories have the correct file permissions. The web server should have appropriate read permissions to access the file.
5. Enable developer mode: Switching to developer mode can provide more detailed error messages. Run the following command to enable developer mode:

   ```
   php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
   ```

- After enabling developer mode, try reproducing the issue and check the error logs again for more specific details about the source file resolution problem.

Comment: In our case we've solved it by upgrading to latest release, but if I should choose one answer I think yours could be the more accurate

Comment: Thanks @RaulSanchez

Answer (score 0):

Please can you verify that in your layout you are not missing

```
<update handle="editor"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Which layout file/s should we check?

Comment: The page you have added page builder - example your_module_form_edit.xml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you gave this file permission.

```
    sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/magento/root/pub/static/adminhtml/
    sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/magento/root/var/
    
    sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/your/magento/root/pub/static/adminhtml/
    sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/your/magento/root/var/
```

the actual user and group(www-data) may be different depending on your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Should try this [Magento Page Builder](https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder) instead